snapd installed applications can't be found by non root
Applications which are installed by snapd are not found(e.g. when I tried to run notepadqq it said that this application is not installed unlike root user it worked and got running) by non-root users
strcuture of /snap (ls -lahHQ /snap):
total 140K
drwx---r-x 34 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "."
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4.0K Aug 31 14:15 ".."
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "bare"
drwx------  2 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "bin"
drwxr-xr--  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:29 "bitcoin-core"
drwxr-xr--  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:30 "canonical-livepatch"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "colorpie"
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:23 "core"
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:21 "core18"
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:22 "core20"
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:23 "core22"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:27 "core24"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  1 16:29 "firmware-updater"
drwxr-xr--  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:34 "gifski"
drwxr-xr--  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:31 "gitea"
drwxr-xr--  3 root root 4.0K Jan  2  2024 "gnome-3-28-1804"
drwxr-xr--  3 root root 4.0K Jan  2  2024 "gnome-3-38-2004"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  1 01:11 "gnome-42-2204"
drwxr-xr--  3 root root 4.0K Jan  2  2024 "gtk-common-themes"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:14 "hetty"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "ipfs"
drwxr-xr--  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:35 "ipfs-desktop"
drwxr-xr--  3 root root 4.0K Jan  2  2024 "kde-frameworks-5-99-qt-5-15-7-core20"
drwxr-xr--  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:43 "metasploit-framework"
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4.0K Sep  4 13:48 "multipass"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:12 "notepadqq"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:14 "password-creator"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "qt513"
-r--r--r--  1 root root  548 May 16  2022 "README"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  1 16:35 "snapd-desktop-integration"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  1 16:33 "snap-store"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:08 "sqlmap"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:08 "sqlmap-cli"
drwxr-xr--  4 root root 4.0K Aug 31 23:30 "terraform"
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:12 "urh"

ACL of snap(getfacl /snap)
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: snap
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::---
other::r-x

structure of /var/lib/snapd (ls -lahHQ /var/lib/snapd)
drwxrwxr--+  24 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:22 "."
drwxr-xr-x+ 151 root root 4.0K Sep  1 18:32 ".."
drwxrwxr-x    4 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "apparmor"
drwxrwxr-x    4 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "assertions"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K Apr 21  2022 "auto-import"
drwxrwx---    2 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:14 "cache"
drwxr-xr-x    2 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "cgroup"
drwxrwx---    2 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "cookie"
drwxrwxr-x    4 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "dbus-1"
drwxrwxr-x    5 root root 4.0K Oct 16  2022 "desktop"
drwxrwxr-x    3 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "device"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K Apr 21  2022 "environment"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root  32K Jan 16  2024 "errtracker.db"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K Dec  4  2023 "features"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K Apr 21  2022 "firstboot"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "hostfs"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "inhibit"
drwxrwxr-x    6 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "lib"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "mount"
drwxrwxr-x    3 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "seccomp"
drwxrwxr-x    2 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "sequence"
drwxrwxr-x    3 root root 4.0K Sep  5 19:17 "snaps"
drwxrwx---    2 root root 4.0K May 11  2023 "snapshots"
drwxrwxr-x    3 root root 4.0K May 16  2022 "ssl"
-rw-------    1 root root 394K Sep  5 19:22 "state.json"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 108K Nov 23  2023 "state.json.5lyNhRNFP8KS~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 111K May 13  2023 "state.json.70KG0xn1hKg6~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 105K Jun 11  2023 "state.json.8BgQdT6FJX75~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 143K Apr  1  2023 "state.json.8HdfDcGyhBFY~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 104K May 31  2023 "state.json.9q5XvtS9nGP9~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 145K Aug 20  2023 "state.json.9xKDtFQ1lRWj~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 124K Aug 23  2023 "state.json.Cj10WFk56Wbh~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 107K May  9  2023 "state.json.dRLRMy7TxNrc~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 109K Jul 16  2023 "state.json.FYkS28VMNCmy~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 110K Oct 25  2023 "state.json.gWY3rGhdnWhg~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 105K May 17  2023 "state.json.H1mdfG39p3Ts~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 145K Apr  1  2023 "state.json.HB1M1JJ0N59J~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 114K Mar 12  2023 "state.json.hLpxgcxdfWrP~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 119K Mar 15  2023 "state.json.KCpN4WlDXv2P~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 120K Dec 23  2022 "state.json.lHWndfY0DjxJ~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 130K Jun 14  2023 "state.json.LsbyfMGYNX82~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 109K Feb 24  2023 "state.json.M33MDQBvkHTp~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 118K Jan 10  2023 "state.json.QmSGQS2CQxgH~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root  82K Sep 19  2022 "state.json.Rmxq8fmYqtGL~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 125K Nov 23  2022 "state.json.sC6gtSnj02MW~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 125K Nov 17  2022 "state.json.SJ1qdwKdN3pS~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 107K Dec 28  2022 "state.json.sPb6h3xYSc5R~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 127K Apr 13  2023 "state.json.tDdL4Wtp44lk~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 113K Mar  1  2023 "state.json.V4KyKK28MJSX~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root  80K Jun 15  2022 "state.json.V5t3g6gchRDn~"
-rw-rwx---    1 root root 148K Jul 13  2023 "state.json.Yfl7t759GFPj~"
-rw-rwxr--    1 root root    0 May 16  2022 "state.lock"
-rw-r--r--    1 root root  790 Sep  1 01:04 "system-key"
-rw-rwxr--    1 root root   10 Jan 10  2023 "system-params"
d--x--x--x    2 root root 4.0K Jan  6  2023 "void"

ACL of /var/lib/snapd(getfacl /var/lib/snapd)
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: var/lib/snapd
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:johnm:r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r--

please note that /var/lib/snapd is a directory on another partition and bound to this directory like
/sdb1/.system-base/var/lib/snapd /var/lib/snapd ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,nouser,async,relatime,bind 0 1
/sdb1/.system-base/var/lib/snapd/mount /var/lib/snapd/mount ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,nouser,async,relatime,bind 0 1

output of the command notepadqq on non root:
Command 'notepadqq' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install notepadqq  # version 1.4.8, or
sudo apt  install notepadqq  # version 2.0.0~beta1-3
See 'snap info notepadqq' for additional versions.

Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Architecture: amd64
Kernel: 6.8.0-40

Seems like The permissions of /snap/bin was strictly set to rwx------ which is possibly the problem
